# input type file, how to get image on screen?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<input hidden type="file" id="inpfile" accept="image/*">

$('#inpfile').change(function(){
    var a = this.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(a);
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var imga = new Image();
        imga.src = e.target.result;
    }
});
```

Where is that image?
How can I really get it on screen and change its style?

Comment: You can append a `img` tag (wherever you want that image). And attribute `src` with value `e.target.result`

Comment: You need to append it an element. Something like `document.body.appendChild(imga)`

Comment: `Where is that image?` why did you put `hidden`?

Comment: @לבנימלכה, input is hidden, but not the image.

Comment: I know it's not your problem here, but don't use a FileReader for displaying a user inputted media in your page. Instead use [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) which will use far less memory and code / callback nightmares.

Comment: @Kaiido, thanks, I'm slightly confused at the moment, but I'll keep in mind your notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `new Image()` you create element in memory only, not in DOM. Create element `<img>` in DOM and use it instead

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var currentIndex = 1;
$('#inpfile').change(function(){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('<img id="img' + currentIndex + '" class="img">') // jQuery will create new element if you pass not CSS selector, but expression, like in this case. Element still in memory
        .attr('src', e.target.result) // Change src attribute of element to base64 encoded image source
        .appendTo('.gallery'); // Append previous created element to <div class="gallery"> in DOM
        currentIndex++; // Increment ID counter, so each element has unique ID
    }
});
});
```

```css
.img {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="inpfile" accept="image/*"/>
<div class="gallery"></div>
```

Comment: can I set `id` instead of `class` and select it by `id` to change its style?

Comment: @puerto Yes if it's the only element with this id on page.

Comment: how can I do that, pls

Comment: $('#img') instead $('.img')

Comment: `#` means `id` and `.` means  `class`

Comment: but that means that I firstly must have an image in DOM with that `id`, and then change its src. I need to SET new ID to the new created image.

Comment: @puerto That's why I suggest using classes. Check another answer update to see how append new elements when input changes.

Comment: @Justinas, why in you code there is no `document.body.appendChild(imga)` part. Where is new created image added to DOM? Thanks, this is my last comment, I promise

Comment: @puerto Because you use jQuery, it's `.appendTo()` function that appends new element from `$('<img>')` to DOM element `.gallery`